# Intent not delivered correctly

Tags: android

I am sending an Intent from GCMIntentService through PendingIntent. I am inserting some strings inside intent and in PendingIntent, I call an activity which will receive intent. But the data is not what I am sending. Here is the screenshot.
[image]

The first Intent shown is what I am sending, and the second is what I am receiving. Here is the code for  sending:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            Group_Chat_MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("group_id", group_id);
                    intent.putExtra("group_title", name);
                    intent.putExtra("from_push", true);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            getBaseContext(), 100,
                            intent, 0);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                            getBaseContext()).setContentTitle("Paisa Swipe")
                            .setContentText(msg)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.home_logo)
                            .setTicker(ticker)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setAutoCancel(true).build();

                    notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(group_id),
                            notification);
```

When I click notification, it sends to the Group_Chat_MainActivity class. In that, I use getIntent() to fetch the Intent data:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getIntent().getStringExtra("group_title")
    getIntent().getStringExtra("group_id")
    getIntent().getBooleanExtra("from_push",false)
    }
```

Here I am getting different strings then what I sent. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your `getBaseContext()` is not null? and this code is in a Fragment?

Comment: for which one you are getting wrong value

Comment: @NoName group_title It is returning strange value "test group". I searched my whole project and there is no String named "test" even in code or xmls :P

Comment: Try using "PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT" flag when building your PendingIntent (instead of 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is your PendingIntent requestCode is same all the time i.e 100. Keep it to be a unique for a group for eg. your group_id. Also your context here should be your GCMIntentService context.Try changing this to

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        getBaseContext(), 100,
                        intent, 0);
```

this

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        yourContextHere, Integer.parseInt(group_id),
                        intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `getBaseContext()` is not null.
If you use it in Fragmnet try:

```
inflatedview.getContext();
```

instead of:

```
getBaseContext()
```

and when you want get value from your intent in `OnCreate` method, try this:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString();
```

instead of:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra();
```

hope this help you.

Comment: First of all, it is a Service, not some View. 
Secondly, the getIntent().getExtras().getString() is depricated.

Comment: @Prince I mentioned it with `If` statement and can you explain me or provide any links for what you say: "**getIntent().getExtras().getString() is depricated.**